# PHP's Memecache in Terms of Memcached

Tags: php, memcached

We have an old PHP application that we're porting to PHP 7.  We would like to move away from the [memcache](http://php.net/memcache) extension, and start using the [memcached](http://php.net/memcache) extension.

However -- we have *a lot* of legacy code written against the [memcache](http://php.net/memcache) APIs and [memcached](http://php.net/memcache) extension is not a drop in replacement.

Is there any known science for dealing with this?  A shim library between the two? Auto conversation tools?  Something we're not thinking of?

Comment: I'd try to find a polyfill, and if it does not exist - it should not be too complicated to implement it. PS: I'm sure this question would be closed as "offtopic: library recommendation"

Comment: The proper solution would be to implement abstractions in your code so that it doesn't matter if you're using one or the other, or Redis, or literally anything else. Simply shimming between two flavors of Memcache extension would be a waste of effort. [php-cache](http://www.php-cache.com/en/latest/) is a solid bet for this.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms -- you say polyfill, I say  shim library :)  I'm hoping the question stays open -- while an existing shim/polyfill is one solution, there may be others, and I'm hoping the question will be received in that spirit.

Comment: @Sammitch Useful information, thank you.  In a world not contained by people's time I'd be right there with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shim/polyfill library for this problem...

https://github.com/mhawker/memcacheshim

It contains guidance and warnings - but looks like a great option if you are trying to get legacy systems ported without a significant cache layer re-write.